# Google Cloud Server Forced Close when Querying for Object Localization

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I sometimes get the error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Upon running

```
# server/classifiers/gcloud/identifier.py


import io
import os
import json
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
from collections import Counter

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

with io.open("config/labels.json", "r") as f:
    LABELS = json.loads(f.read())


def identify_from_string(blob):
    image = types.Image(content=blob)
    response = client.object_localization(image=image)
    labels = response.localized_object_annotations
    objects = set(label.name for label in labels)

    c = Counter()
    for label, s in LABELS.items():
        for ob in objects:
            if ob in s:
                c[label] += s[ob]

    if not c: print("Sorry, the server is currently full.")
    return str(c)
```

With the error thrown on line with `response = client.object_localization(image=image)`. On my `app.py`, I have

```
# server/app.py

import os
import json
from server.classifiers.gcloud import identifier
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, send_file, request

@app.route('/classify', methods=['POST'])
def classify():
    app.logger.info("Got image to /classify")
    file = request.files['image']
    blob = file.read()
    results = identifier.identify_from_string(blob)
    return Response(response=json.dumps(dict(response)), status=200)
```

Where the server.classifiers.gcloud.identifier points to the file above. Occasionally, the issue suddenly goes away. Is there a way around this?

Comment: This sounds like a bug or a problem w/ the API, can you file this as an issue at https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/issues?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem but the issue happens occasionally. Any resolution or work around for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's a good chance that you need to download the service account credentials and export the environment variables as well as your GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT, e.g. on *nix:

```
export GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=blue-jet-123
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$HOME/path/to/service.json
```

I'm trying to reproduce the error but my flask server isn't starting, can you indicate the contents of "config/labels.json, you can tree your folder to make sure we have the same directory structure

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Gal. When posting an answer, you should only post a full and complete one. Requests for clarification should be posted as comments. I know you probably cannot post comments yet, but this will become possible very soon. For now, concentrate on answering questions you can answer in full using the data provided by the asker.